# Integral $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x^2\sqrt{\tan x}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, alternative-proof

Last year I wondered about this integral:$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x^2\sqrt{\tan x}\,\mathrm dx$$
That is because it looks very similar to this [integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2843167/515527)
 and this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2852908/515527). Surprisingly the result is quite nice and an approach can be  found [here](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1760181p11509022).
$$\boxed{\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x^2\sqrt{\tan x}\,\mathrm dx=\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi(5\pi^2+12\pi\ln 2 - 12\ln^22)}{96}}$$

Although the approach there is quite skillful, I believed that an elementary approach can be found for this integral.

Here is my idea. First we will consider the following two integrals: $$I=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x^2\sqrt{\tan x}\,\mathrm dx \,;\quad J=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x^2\sqrt{\cot x}\,\mathrm dx$$
$$\Rightarrow I=\frac12 \left((I-J)+(I+J)\right)$$
Thust we need to evaluate the sum and the difference of those two from above.

I also saw from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1921384/515527) that the "sister" integral differs only by a minus sign: $$\boxed{\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x^2\sqrt{\cot x}\,\mathrm dx=\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi(5\pi^2-12\pi\ln 2 - 12\ln^22)}{96}}$$
Thus using those two boxed answer we expect to find: $$I-J=\frac{\pi^2 \ln  2}{2\sqrt 2};\quad I+J=\frac{5\pi^3}{24\sqrt 2}-\frac{\pi \ln^2 2}{2\sqrt 2}\tag1$$

---

$$I-J=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x^2\left(\sqrt{\tan x}-\sqrt{\cot x}\right)\,\mathrm dx=\sqrt 2\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x^2 \cdot \frac{\sin x-\cos x}{\sqrt{\sin (2x)}}dx$$
$$=-\sqrt 2\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x^2 \left(\operatorname{arccosh}(\sin x+\cos x) \right)'dx=2\sqrt 2 \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x\operatorname{arccosh} (\sin x+\cos x)dx$$
Let us also denote the last integral with $I_1$ and do a $\frac{\pi}{2}-x=x$ substitution: 
$$I_1=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x\operatorname{arccosh} (\sin x+\cos x)dx=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)\operatorname{arccosh} (\sin x+\cos x)dx$$
$$2I_1=\frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \operatorname{arccosh} (\sin x+\cos x)dx\Rightarrow I-J=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt 2}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \operatorname{arccosh} (\sin x+\cos x)dx$$

By using $(1)$ we can easily deduce that: $$\bbox[10pt,#000, border:2px solid green ]{\color{orange}{\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \operatorname{arccosh} (\sin x+\cos x)dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln 2}}$$

---

Doing something similar for $I+J$ we get:
$$I+J=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x^2\left(\sqrt{\tan x}+\sqrt{\cot x}\right)\,\mathrm dx=\sqrt 2\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x^2 \cdot \frac{\sin x+\cos x}{\sqrt{\sin (2x)}}dx$$
$$=\sqrt 2 \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x^2 \left( \arcsin \left(\sin x-\cos x\right)\right)'dx=\frac{\pi^3 \sqrt 2}{8}-2\sqrt 2 \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x \arcsin \left(\sin x-\cos x\right)dx$$

Unfortunately, we're not lucky this time and the substitution used for $I-J$ doesn't help in this case. 
Of course using $(1)$ we can again  deduce that: 
$$\bbox[10pt,#000, border:2px solid green ]{\color{red}{\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x \arcsin \left(\sin x-\cos x\right)dx=\frac{\pi^3}{96}+\frac{\pi}{8}\ln^2 2}}$$

---

In the meantime I found  a way for the first one, mainly using: $$\frac{\arctan x}{x}=\int_0^1 \frac{dy}{1+x^2y^2}$$ Let us denote: $$I_1=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \operatorname{arccosh} (\sin x+\cos x)dx\overset{IBP}= \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x \cdot \frac{\sin x-\cos x}{\sqrt{\sin(2x)}}dx$$
$$\overset{\tan x\rightarrow x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan x}{1+x^2}\frac{x-1}{\sqrt x}dx=\frac1{\sqrt 2}\int_0^\infty \int_0^1 \frac{dy}{1+x^2y^2} \frac{\sqrt x(x-1)}{1+x^2}dx$$
$$=\frac1{\sqrt 2}\int_0^1 \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+y^2x^2} \frac{\sqrt x(x-1)}{1+x^2} dxdy$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\int_0^1 \frac{{\pi}}{\sqrt 2}\left(\frac{2}{y^2-1}-\frac{1}{\sqrt y (y^2-1)}-\frac{\sqrt y}{y^2-1}\right)dy=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln 2$$

Although the integral in the third row looks quite unpleasant, it can be done quite elementary.

---

Sadly a similar approach for the second one is madness, because we would have:
$$I_2=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt x (x+1)}{1+x^2}\frac{1}{1+y^2x^2}\frac{1}{1+z^2x^2} dxdydz$$

But atleast it gives hope that an elementary approach exists.

> For this question I would like to see an elementary approach (without relying on special functions) for the second integral (red one).

If possible please avoid contour integration, although this might be
included in  *elementary*.

Comment: I look forward to being about to integrate as you do. Very nice work here.

Comment: Hi Zacky .. have you tried substituting $\pi/2-x=t$?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On the path of Zacky, the missing part...

Let,

\begin{align}I&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x^2\sqrt{\tan x}\,dx\\
J&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{\tan x}}\,dx\\
\end{align}

Perform the change of variable $y=\sqrt{\tan x}$,

\begin{align}I&=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{2x^2\arctan^2\left(x^2\right)}{1+x^4}\,dx\\\\
J&=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{2x^2\arctan^2\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{1+x^4}\,dx\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\text{I+J}&=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{2x^2\left(\arctan\left(x^2\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)^2}{1+x^4}\,dx-4\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2\arctan\left(x^2\right)\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{1+x^4}\,dx\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{4}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{2x^2}{1+x^4}\,dx-4\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2\arctan\left(x^2\right)\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{1+x^4}\,dx\\
\end{align}

Perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{1}{x}$,

\begin{align}
\text{K}&=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{2x^2}{1+x^4}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{2}{1+x^4}\,dx\\
\end{align}

Therefore,

\begin{align}
\text{2K}=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{2\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^2+2}\,dx
\end{align}

Perform the change of variable $y=x-\dfrac{1}{x}$,

\begin{align}\text{2K}&=2\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2+x^2}\,dx\\
&=2\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right]_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\\
&=2\times \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{align}

therefore,

\begin{align}
\text{I+J}&=\frac{\pi^3}{4\sqrt{2}}-4\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2\arctan\left(x^2\right)\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{1+x^4}\,dx\\
\end{align}

Let $a>0$,

\begin{align}
\text{K}_1(a)&=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{a+x^4}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{a}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{1+\left(a^{-\frac{1}{4}}x\right)^4}\,dx\\
\end{align}

Perform the change of variable $y=a^{-\frac{1}{4}}x$,

\begin{align}
\text{K}_1(a)&=a^{-\frac{1}{4}}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}\,dx\\
&=\frac{a^{-\frac{1}{4}}\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}
\end{align}

In the same manner,

\begin{align}
\text{K}_2(a)&=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{1+ax^4}\,dx\\
&=\frac{a^{-\frac{3}{4}}\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}
\end{align}

Since, for $a$ real,

\begin{align}\arctan a=\int_0^1 \frac{a}{1+a^2t^2}\,dt\end{align}

then,

\begin{align}\text{L}&=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2\arctan\left(x^2\right)\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{1+x^4}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}\left(\int_0^1 \int_0^1  \frac{x^2}{(1+u^2x^4)\left(1+\frac{v^2}{x^4}\right)(1+x^4)}\,du\,dv\right)\,dx\\
&=\\
&\int_0^{\infty}\left(\int_0^1\int_0^1 \left(\frac{x^2}{(1-u^2)(1-v^2)(1+x^4)}-\frac{x^2}{1-u^2v^2}\left(\frac{u^2}{(1-u^2)(1+u^2x^4)}+\frac{v^2}{(1-v^2)(v^2+x^4)}\right)
\right)dudv\right)dx\\
&=\int_0^1\int_0^1 \left(\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}(1-u^2)(1-v^2)}-\frac{1}{1-u^2v^2}\left(\frac{u^2\text{K}_2(u^2)}{1-u^2}+\frac{v^2\text{K}_1(v^2)}{1-v^2}\right)\right)dudv\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}\int_0^1\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{(1-u^2)(1-v^2)}-\frac{1}{(1-u^2v^2)}\left(\frac{u^{\frac{1}{2}}}{1-u^2}+\frac{v^{\frac{3}{2}}}{1-v^2}\right)\right)dudv\\
&=\pi\int_0^1\left[\frac{\sqrt{v}\left(\text{ arctanh}\left(\sqrt{uv}\right)-\text{ arctan}\left(\sqrt{uv}\right)-\text{ arctanh}\left(uv\right)\right)+\arctan\left(\sqrt{u}\right)+\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+u}}{1+\sqrt{u}}\right)}{2\sqrt{2}(1-v^2)}\right]_{u=0}^{u=1}\,dv\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{v}\big(\text{ arctanh}\left(\sqrt{v}\right)-\text{ arctan}\left(\sqrt{v}\right)-\text{ arctanh}\left(v\right)\big)+\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\ln 2}{1-v^2}\,dv\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{v}\arctan\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{v}}{1+\sqrt{v}}\right)}{1-v^2}\,dv+\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\ln 2\right)\int_0^1 \frac{1-\sqrt{v}}{1-v^2}\,dv+\\
&\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{v}\ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{v}}{2}\right)}{1-v^2}\,dv-\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{2}}\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{v}\ln\left(\frac{1+v}{2}\right)}{1-v^2}\,dv
\end{align}

Perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{1-\sqrt{v}}{1+\sqrt{v}}$,

\begin{align}\text{R}_1&=\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{v}\arctan\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{v}}{1+\sqrt{v}}\right)}{1-v^2}\,dv\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{(1-v)^2\arctan v}{v(1+v^2)}\,dv\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan v}{v}\,dv-\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan v}{1+v^2}\,dv\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\text{G}-\frac{1}{2}\Big[\arctan^2 v\Big]_0^1\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\text{G}-\frac{\pi^2}{32}\\
\text{R}_2&=\int_0^1 \frac{1-\sqrt{v}}{1-v^2}\,dv\\
&=\left[\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+v}}{1+\sqrt{v}}\right)+\arctan\left(\sqrt{v}\right)\right]_0^1\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\ln 2\\
\end{align}

Perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{1-\sqrt{v}}{1+\sqrt{v}}$,

\begin{align}\text{R}_3&=\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{v}\ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{v}}{2}\right)}{1-v^2}\,dv\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{(1-v)^2\ln(1+v)}{v(1+v^2)}\,dv\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+v)}{1+v^2}\,dv-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+v
)}{v}\,dv\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+v)}{1+v^2}\,dv-\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{2v\ln(1-v^2)}{v^2}\,dv+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-v)}{v}\,dv\\
\end{align}

In the second integral perform the change of variable $y=v^2$,

\begin{align}\text{R}_3&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+v)}{1+v^2}\,dv+\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-v)}{v}\,dv\\
\end{align}

In the second integral perform the change of variable $y=1-v$,

\begin{align}\text{R}_3&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+v)}{1+v^2}\,dv+\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln v}{1-v}\,dv\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+v)}{1+v^2}\,dv+\frac{1}{4}\times -\zeta(2)\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+v)}{1+v^2}\,dv-\frac{\pi^2}{24}\\
\end{align}

Perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{1-v}{1+v}$,

\begin{align}
\text{S}_1&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+v)}{1+v^2}\,dv\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(\frac{2}{1+v})}{1+v^2}\,dv\\
&=\ln 2\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+v^2}\,dv-\text{S}_1\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln 2-\text{S}_1
\end{align}

Therefore,

\begin{align}
\text{S}_1&=\frac{\pi}{8}\ln 2\\
\text{R}_3&=\frac{\pi}{8}\ln 2-\frac{\pi^2}{24}\\
\end{align}

Perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{1-\sqrt{v}}{1+\sqrt{v}}$,

\begin{align}
\text{R}_4&=\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{v}\ln\left(\frac{1+v}{2}\right)}{1-v^2}\,dv\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{(1-v)^2\ln\left(\frac{1+v^2}{(1+v)^2}\right)}{v(1+v^2)}\,dv\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{(1-v)^2\ln\left(1+v^2\right)}{v(1+v^2)}\,dv+2\text{R}_3\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+v^2)}{v}\,dv-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+v^2)}{1+v^2}\,dv+\frac{\pi}{4}\ln 2-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{4}\zeta(2)-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+v^2)}{1+v^2}\,dv+\frac{\pi}{4}\ln 2-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln 2-\frac{\pi^2}{16}-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+v^2)}{1+v^2}\,dv\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln 2-\frac{\pi^2}{16}-\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{v^2}{(1+v^2)(1+v^2t)}\,dt\,dv\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln 2-\frac{\pi^2}{16}-\int_0^1 \left[\frac{\arctan\left(v\right)\sqrt{t}-\arctan\left(v\sqrt{t}\right)}{(t-1)\sqrt{t}}\right]_{v=0}^{v=1}\,dt\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln 2-\frac{\pi^2}{16}-\int_0^1 \frac{\frac{\pi\sqrt{t}}{4}-\arctan\left(\sqrt{t}\right)}{(t-1)\sqrt{t}}\,dt\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln 2-\frac{\pi^2}{16}+\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{t}}{1+\sqrt{t}}\right)}{(1-t)\sqrt{t}}\,dt-\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{t}-1}{(t-1)\sqrt{t}}\,dt\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln 2-\frac{\pi^2}{16}+\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{t}}{1+\sqrt{t}}\right)}{(1-t)\sqrt{t}}\,dt-\frac{\pi}{4}\Big[2\ln\left(1+\sqrt{t}\right)\Big]_0^1\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{t}}{1+\sqrt{t}}\right)}{(1-t)\sqrt{t}}\,dt-\frac{\pi}{4}\ln 2-\frac{\pi^2}{16}\\
\end{align}

Perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{1-\sqrt{t}}{1+\sqrt{t}}$,

\begin{align}
\text{R}_4&=\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan t}{t}\,dt-\frac{\pi}{4}\ln 2-\frac{\pi^2}{16}\\
&=\text{G}-\frac{\pi}{4}\ln 2-\frac{\pi^2}{16}\\
\end{align}

Therefore,

\begin{align}L&=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}\text{R}_1+\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\ln 2\right) \text{R}_2+\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}\text{R}_3-\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{2}}\text{R}_4\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(\frac{\text{G}}{2}-\frac{\pi^2}{32}\right)+\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\ln 2\right)^2+\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\ln 2-\frac{\pi^2}{24}\right)-\\
&\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{2}}\left(\text{G}-\frac{\pi}{4}\ln 2-\frac{\pi^2}{16}\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi^3}{96\sqrt{2}}+\frac{\pi\ln^2 2}{8\sqrt{2}}
\end{align}

Thus,
\begin{align}\text{I+J}&=\frac{\pi^3}{4\sqrt{2}}-4\text{L}\\
&=\frac{\pi^3}{4\sqrt{2}}-4\left(\frac{\pi^3}{96\sqrt{2}}+\frac{\pi\ln^2 2}{8\sqrt{2}}\right)\\
&=\boxed{\frac{5\pi^3}{24\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\pi\ln^2 2}{2\sqrt{2}}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 9):

Both integrals depend on
$$\int_{0}^{\pi} x^2 \frac{\sqrt{1+\cos x}\pm \sqrt{1-\cos x}}{\sqrt{\sin x}}\,dx=\\\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\sin x}}\left[(x^2\pm(\pi-x)^2)\sqrt{1+\cos x}+(\pm x^2+(\pi-x)^2)\sqrt{1-\cos x}\right]\,dx $$
and they can be tackled through the Fourier series of a periodic version of $x^2\pm(\pi-x)^2$. For instance

$$ x^2+(\pi-x)^2 = \frac{2\pi^2}{3}+2\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos(2nx)}{n^2}\qquad \forall x\in[0,\pi] $$
(yes, I am exploiting Bernoulli polynomials) and for any $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sqrt{1+\cos x}+\sqrt{1-\cos x}}{\sqrt{\sin x}}\cos(2nx)\,dx=\frac{\pi}{4^n\sqrt{2}}\binom{2n}{n}$$
so the whole question boils down to computing
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2 4^n}\binom{2n}{n} = \frac{1}{2}\,\phantom{}_4 F_3\left(1,1,1,\tfrac{3}{2};2,2,2;1\right)=\zeta(2)-2\log^2(2).$$
The last equality follows by recalling $\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\sin t)^{2n}\,dt$ and by tackling
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\text{Li}_2(z)}{\sqrt{z(1-z)}}\,dz $$
through [Fourier-Legendre series](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.08411) or the reflection formula for $\text{Li}_2$.
 The remaining part is just related to the well-known
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\,dx = 4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log\sin\theta\,d\theta = -2\pi\log 2.$$
Summarizing, all the involved integrals just depend on $\left.\frac{d^\nu}{da^\nu}B\left(a,\tfrac{1}{2}\right)\right|_{a=1/2}$ for $\nu\in\{1,2\}$.

Comment: I don't know if this fits the requirements for 'elementary', but nice job anyway

Comment: Could you give me a tip on proving $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac1{4^n n^2}{2n\choose n}=\zeta(2)-2\log^22$$?

Comment: The value of this series is (integrate first using variable t) \begin{align}\sum_{n\geq 1}^\infty \frac{1}{4^n n^2}\binom{2n}{n}&=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{x=0}^1\int_{t=0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\ln x\sin^2 t }{x\sin^2 t-1}\,dt\,dx\end{align}